# Difference between "both ways" and "in both ways"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between the two sentences given below?

> You cannot have it both ways.
>   You cannot have it in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase **both ways** refers to a pair of options or choices. The statement *You cannot have it both ways* normally is used to say that these options are mutually exclusive: you can have the one or the other but not both.

> You can live out in the country or in the city. You cannot have it both ways.

The pronoun  **it** there refers vaguely to an existential condition.

The phrase **in both ways** is similar, but with the addition of the preposition  **in**, it refers to a pair of choices respecting the *manner* of something.

> You can have your ice-cream in a dish, or you can have an ice-cream cone; you cannot have it in both ways.

The pronoun **it** there refers to **ice-cream**, and **both ways** refers to the manner of serving it, in a dish or on a cone.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is the same.
The order of words gets tested in relation to parallel structures.

The phrases that follow **BOTH** must be parallel. Both your sentences follow this rule "both ways" and "in both ways" are parallel.

But this specific phrase, I mean, "**somebody can’t have it both ways**" used to say that someone cannot have the advantages that come from two separate situations because they cannot exist together:

> It’s either **me** or **her**. You **can’t have it both ways**.

Saying "**It’s either me or her. You can’t have it in both ways**" is not wrong, but it sounds a little weird to me.